# protected static in base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just inherited an ASP.NET MVC4 application that has a base class with the following member:

```
protected static DBMainDataContext m_dataContext = new DBMainDataContext();
```

This base class is inherited by two other classes that both use LINQ to read data from the database. The fact that this base class has a static data context, does this pose a problem? We seem to be getting errors along the line where the DataReader cannot be accessed because it is already opened. Could this be the reason why? If yes, how should it be declared? Do I simply remove the static keyword?

Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, reusing an instance of `DBContext` or `ObjectContext` seems to be a bad idea. I would argue the best way to do this is to create some `Func<DBMainDataContext>` which returns a new instance of it every time it's required.

Comment: @HighCore Technically no need to change anything but the static keyword, since the controller containing it is instantiated by MVC for every request.

Comment: do you properly close the datareader when you are done reading data from the database?

Comment: @MortenMertner agreed, however there may be conflicts even during a single request, so that would depend on the actual usage of the `Context`.

Comment: @HighCore it's hard to imagine how a single web request can have any conflicts, given that a single thread is used for the entire request.

Comment: @ryrich There is no explicit code that manipulates the DataReader in the application. Everything is done through LINQ using SubmitChanges(). I'm assuming LINQ opens datareaders implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, removing the `static` keyword is the way to go.

If this is a LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework Context then object construction cost should be very low, and hence you should use a new instance for every request.

You should probably also verify that your DataReaders are properly closed (as ryrich suggested). The best way to ensure this is to wrap their usage in a using-block:

```
using( var reader = ... )
{
    // code to use the reader here
}
```

Comment: This is a LINQ to SQL context, and as I mentioned, there is no explicit manipulation of a DataReader in the code, so I assume LINQ uses one behind the scenes. I'll try removing the static keyword and see if we get any more of these errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general rule that static members should be thread safe. So, your static `m_dataContext` should be thread safe.

`DBMainDataContext` is not thread safe. So if two threads (two ASP.NET request) access then data context, its is modified by two threads at the same time. This will lead to conflicts.

So you have two options:

1. Remove the `static` and have one data context per thread.
2. Synchronize access to the data context by place a lock arround all the calls using it.

Comment: And be advised that option 2 is a pretty brainless solution to the problem, considering that this is a web app.